# get_dummies() for multiple Pandas DataFrame's

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of DataFrames and I would like to one-hot encode some of the columns in place. For example, if:

```
In[1]:  df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['a', 'a'], ['b', 'b'], ['c', 'c']]), 
                   columns=['col_1', 'col_2'])
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['a', 'a'], ['b', 'b'], ['c', 'c']]),
                   columns=['col_1', 'col_2'])

        combined = [df1, df2]
        combined


Out[1]:    col_1  col_2
        0      a      a
        1      b      b
        2      c      c
```

I'm currently using the following approach.

```
In[2]:  for df in combined:
            one_hot = pd.get_dummies(df["col_2"])

            df[one_hot.columns] = one_hot
            df.drop("col_2", axis=1, inplace=True)

        
        df1

Out[2]:      col_1   a   b   c
          0      a   1   0   0
          1      b   0   1   0 
          2      c   0   0   1
```

Am I missing a more concise solution?

---

### Edit

An important requirement is that I need to modify the original dataframes.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your approach.  The only way to make it more concise would be to overwrite the dataframes completely.  I'll show an example.

Comment: After rereading, if you insist on doing it in place, then what you've got already is what I'd do.

Comment: I see, thank you. If you had multiple dataframes with the same index and columns, would you use the exact same approach (i.e. with a list) or would you choose another solution? Most of the solution that I've seen choose a list but this may not be the best way?

Comment: The "issue" is that normally we don't use a set of named dataframes for which we want to preserve the object referenced by all those names.  Meaning, it isn't important that we keep making changes in place.  I usually just overwrite the name `df1` with a new calculation of `df1`.  However, this question focuses on doing it in place.  In reality, you're just adding some columns in place and deleting a column in place.  You loop over each one to do so.  That is straight forward.

Comment: I updated my answer with a way to assign to all names again.

Comment: Understood, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### OP's method is just fine

```
for df in combined:
    one_hot = pd.get_dummies(df["col_2"])

    df[one_hot.columns] = one_hot
    df.drop("col_2", axis=1, inplace=True)
```

---

#### Reassign to all names

```
df1, df2 = [df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['col_2'])).drop('col_2', 1) for df in combined]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can using `concat` with `key` which will add a new level of index  , then `get_dummies`

```
s=pd.concat(combined,keys=range(len(combined)))['col_2'].str.get_dummies()
s['col_1']=pd.concat(combined,keys=range(len(combined)))['col_1'].values

s
Out[20]: 
     a  b  c col_1
0 0  1  0  0     a
  1  0  1  0     b
  2  0  0  1     c
1 0  1  0  0     a
  1  0  1  0     b
  2  0  0  1     c
```

If you would like to save them into a list for different dfs , you can `groupby` and save it to `dict`

```
d={x:y.reset_index(level=0,drop=True) for x , y in s.groupby(level=0)}
d
Out[16]: 
{0:    a  b  c
 0  1  0  0
 1  0  1  0
 2  0  0  1, 1:    a  b  c
 0  1  0  0
 1  0  1  0
 2  0  0  1}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have edited my question to clarify that I need to modify the original dataframe's. So it's necessary that I can call one of the original dataframe names and the modified solution is returned

Comment: @Josmoor98 you mean you want change the original dataframe ?